# I resized my GCP instance but the new size isn't showing up when I run "df"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I resized my GCP instance and added a few hundred gigs, but when I run `df` in my console, I don't see that the disk size has changed. Why isn't the new space showing up?

EDIT: So I've been following the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

But my partition table looks different:

`` NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  600G  0 disk
`-sda1   8:1    0  100G  0 part / ``

I tried the following command to grow the partition, but it threw up an error:

`JTa:~$ sudo growpart /dev/sda1 1
WARN: unknown label
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: device contains a valid 'ext4' signature; it is strongly recommended to wipe the device with wipefs(8) if this is unexpected, in order to avoid possible collisions
sfdisk: failed to dump partition table: Success
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/sda1`

Comment: This post is out of StackOverflow communityś scope, please ask your question on ServerFault forum. Just to help, have a look at this page : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

Comment: Which OS? Did you reboot the VM instance? I wrote a how-to article on this topic: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. According to the documentation, we shouldn't need to reboot the VM. I tried following the steps in the guide posted by @Tzigan  but I'm stuck. My partition table looks different than the one in the guide, I edited OP

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo growpart /dev/sda 1